# Tabs on Drawer Navigation screens with React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I was given a pretty complicated app layout and I am still new to React Native so I am pretty stuck.

Currently I have a router file that I am calling in my App.js.

Basically the layout needs to be Tabs AND a Drawer on every page but I have some pages that are only referenced through the DrawerNavigator so they don’t have the Tabs on those pages.
Basically in the code below I need the “UserCreate” Stack to be accessible from the drawer nav but also have the tabs on the pages.

I have tried nesting the Drawer and Tabs into another StackNavigator but that doesn’t seem to be working. Anyone have any ideas?

```
export const Checkout = createStackNavigator ({
    Cart: {screen: Cart},
    ThankYou: {screen: ThankYou}
 },{
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    }
}
);

export const MenuNav = createStackNavigator ({
    Location: {screen: Location},
    Menu: {screen: Menu},
    CategoryDetails: {screen: CategoryDetails},
    ItemDetails: {screen: ItemDetails},
    },
    {
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    }
  },
);

export const UserCreate = createStackNavigator ({
    Login: {screen: Login},
    SignUp: {screen: SignUp},
    Profile: {screen: Profile},
    }, {
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    }
})

export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    'Home': {
         screen: Home,
          },
    'Items': {
         screen: MenuNav,
          },
      },
    'Cart': {
         screen: Checkout,
      },
    'Info': {
         screen: Info,
       },
    },
    {
         tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
     },
);


export const createRootNavigator = () => {
    return createDrawerNavigator ({
        Home: {
            screen: Tabs
         },
        Profiles: {
            screen: UserCreate    
        }
        }, {
            initialRouteName: 'Home',
            contentComponent: SideNav,
            drawerWidth: 200,
        });

}
```